# How can I customise the comparison PDF of Magento 2.1 PDF invoice layout

Tags: magento-2.1, invoice, pdf

How can I customise the comparison PDF of Magento 2.1 PDF invoice layout?

I want to change the content of comparaison pdf (format) in magento 2.1

I want to remove header and footer section from pdf format and href links.

Comment: any solution for this @sukumar Gorai

Comment: Can you post your layout what do you want?

Comment: https://prnt.sc/kl72u9  - I need only compare products without header and footer section and href links

Comment: You need to include dompdf or fpdf then create pdf accordingly.